# Update UIProgressView on UITableViewCell

Tags: tableview, uiprogressview

At the moment I got my main tableview with cells, which are loaded from a XML and filled up. After that I can click on one cell and a detailview is loaded(xib file, loaded through code in the main tableview). On the detailview I can click a download button and some files are downloaded asynchron to the documents folder. Then I pop the view down and I see again my tableview.

My idea now is to see the progress of the download in the tableview cell. I set up a uiprogressview on every cell, which is hidden on default. I now want to see the progress bar when I start the download. How can I do that?

I tried something with performSelectorOnMainThread and a selector, which change the progress of my selected cell(which I assign in the main tableview). Seems to be a bad idea - didnt work.

Some ideas how to do that?

---

EDIT2: Some piece of code of my solution, ATTENTION! This is not the real code, I deleted a lot of lines for inserting here. There arent all releases etc. I think the solution is really dirty, but I didnt found a better solution for me...

Some important things:

- cellDownloading: Array which knows
  every cell which is downloading at
  the moment
- progressDictionary: Knows the progress of every cell
- cellDictionary: Knows every cell, filled up in the cellsForRowAtIndexpath delegte of the tableview

I also cant copy the whole code, because there is a lot which have nothing to do with the whole process, but I give you the important steps.
My cells are created through parsing a xml, so every cell has got a setId in my case.

//////////////////
// Downloader.mm
//////////////////

method to download asynchron

```
-(void)startAsynchronousDownload:(NSString*)path{    

// generate notification
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSNumber *tmpSetId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:setId];

[userInfo setObject:tmpSetId forKey:@"setId"];

NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"downloadStackNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo];  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];  

// add some infos...
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:tmpSetId forKey:@"setId"];
// perhaps more here

// asynchronous download handling
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(downloadImagesWithDictionary:) object:dictionary];

// release
[operation release];
[dictionary release];
[userInfo release];
}
```

In my example the selector downloadImagesWithDictionary downloads some images, for every downloaded image I send a notification. Every stack of images have a setId in my case.

```
[...]
    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSNumber *sliceCounter = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    NSNumber *amount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:amountOfImages];
    NSNumber *tmpSetId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:setId];

    [userInfo setObject:sliceCounter forKey:@"actualImage"];
    [userInfo setObject:amount forKey:@"allImages"];
    [userInfo setObject:tmpSetId forKey:@"setId"];
    NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"downloadSliceNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo];  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification ];  
[...]
```

////////////////////////////
// TableViewController.mm
////////////////////////////

Now we need to get the notifications to update our tableview

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(downloadSliceNotification:) name:@"downloadSliceNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(downloadStackNotification:) name:@"downloadStackNotification" object:nil];
```

We need a cell dictionary to know all indexpath of our existing tableview cells.
Fill them in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate

```
[cellDictionary setObject:indexPath forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cellSetId]];
```

Now we create the handler to do somehting if we got a notification
First the handler if the download starts
I have got a progress dictionary which knows every progress of every cell
I can identify every cell by the setId - perhaps u have to change that a little bit

```
- (void)downloadStackNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {  
NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
NSNumber *setId = [userInfo objectForKey:@"setId"];

NSNumber *progress = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];    
[progressDictionary setObject:progress forKey:[setId stringValue]];

// add cell to downloadlist
[cellDownloading addObject:[setId stringValue]];
```

}

Now for every download step(in my case one image). 
Calculate process and update the dictionary, get the cell to update the progress

```
- (void)downloadSliceNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {  
NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
NSNumber *sliceCounter = [userInfo objectForKey:@"actualImage"];
NSNumber *amount = [userInfo objectForKey:@"allImages"]; 
NSNumber *setId = [userInfo objectForKey:@"setId"]; 

NSNumber *progress = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(100/[amount floatValue])*[sliceCounter floatValue]];      

[progressDictionary setObject:progress forKey:[setId stringValue]];
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [cellDictionary objectForKey:[setId stringValue]];

CustomServerCell* cell = (CustomServerCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSMutableDictionary *downloadData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[downloadData setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];
[downloadData setObject:sliceCounter forKey:@"actualImage"];
[downloadData setObject:amount forKey:@"allImages"];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressWithDictionary:) withObject:downloadData waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Update the cell

```
-(void)updateProgressWithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary*)downloadData {

CustomServerCell* cell = (CustomServerCell*)[downloadData objectForKey:@"cell"];
NSNumber *sliceCounter = [downloadData objectForKey:@"actualImage"];
NSNumber *amount = [downloadData objectForKey:@"allImages"];

cell.progressView.hidden = FALSE;
NSNumber *tmpProgress = [progressDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cell.progressView.tag]];
cell.progressView.progress = [tmpProgress floatValue]/100;
cell.statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"download slice %d / %d",[sliceCounter integerValue],[amount integerValue]];
```

}

Comment: Did you use the setProgressBar function ?

Comment: I dont know this function?:o I just set up a uiprogressview on my cell and set the progress with cell.progressView.progress = x;

Comment: Na. Nevermind. That is just an outlet for UIProgressView. Why did you not use performSelectorOnMainThread ?

Comment: I tried it in some way like that in the detailview:    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(testWithCell:) withObject:cell waitUntilDone:NO];

In the selector I update the cell.progressView.progress. Should that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem know. Because I use tableviewcells which are read from a XML over the internet I had some problems with the reloading of the tableview. I made know the following process to success:

1. Create notification for every
   download step(in my case Im
   downloading slice per slice)
2. Register a observer in the main
   tableview class
3. Create handler
   for the notification
4. Send
   download infos as userinfo
   dictionary in the notifcation
5. Save progress of every download
   order in a dictionary with a
   identify as key(in my case a set id)
6. Create a selector and read out
   the dictionary and set the process
   on the right cell
7. Add the selector to the performSelectorOnMainThread

Dont know if it is a good solution - but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar:) withObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:pr] waitUntilDone: YES]
```

instead of

```
progressView.progress += 0.1; // or any other number for that matter
```

Comment: I tried that, but didnt help. In my question I added some piece of code. The problem is, that it changes to the main view after the whole selector process is over. So I cant see the loading process of the progress bar.